# Jenkins: How to keep specific builds longer?

Tags: jenkins

I have a declarative pipeline that executes almost regularly.
Upon specific condition (evaluated during the job run) I'd like to keep the job longer than usual.

- Usual runs I keep for one week.
- If condition 1 is true I want to keep the build for up to a month.
- If condition 2 is true, I want to keep the build for up to six months.

Can Jenkins do something like that out of the box, or can it do it by adding some plugin?

Comment: are you using jenkins declarative pipeline or something else ?

Comment: Yes, it is a declarative pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this job: Jenkins out of the box cannot do what I was searching for. However Jenkins can run plugins. Not finding any plugin that would satisfy my need I started creating my own. Here are the highlevel steps if someone wanted to do the same:

- follow the [Jenkins Plugin development tutorial](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/). From that you have a plugin with a build step and a build action
- modify the build action to store the information about the two conditions, or even better the resulting keep period.
- modify the build step so the information can be set from freestyle builds or pipeline steps.
- create a BuildDiscarder that reads the information from the action and honors it before triggering a delete